# Passing format as parameter to rake spec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890521/how-to-pass-f-specdoc-option-through-rake-task) , where they want to override `rake spec`'s output format.  The resolution to that question is to use the .rspec config file, which is limiting.  I would like this to be a command line argument because  I want this to vary on different machines.

The rspec executable has the `-f` option be defining format. `rake spec` has `-f` defining a rakefile. `rake spec --format` is invalid.  Is this an oversight in `rake spec`?  "Format" really isn't an option?

Comment: Since you found the answer yourself, best to add it as an answer below as well; will help others who come up with the same question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

ANSWER: I'm self answering my question here. rake spec will take the SPEC_OPTS environment variable.

```
rake spec SPEC_OPTS="--format documentation"
```

Comment: Works great for `--seed=12345`!

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner way todo this in `Rakefile`:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = '--format documentation'
end
```